# Sharing Windows clipboard with i3 in Virtualbox VM

Tags: linux, virtualbox, clipboard

I'm running a Sabayon Linux VM inside of Virtualbox 4.3.  I have the guest additions installed, and when I run a desktop environment such as XFCE, I have bidirectional clipboard support (via Control-Shift-C/V in the VM) with my Windows 8 host.  Recently, I switched to i3 to try it out, and while I'm enjoying it, I no longer have access to the Windows clipboard.  How can I regain access to the Windows clipboard in i3?  Note that I am running i3 without a desktop environment.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you have virtualbox-guest-utils installed you can simply run:

```
/usr/bin/VBoxClient-all
```

And if you're launching i3 with startx you can add that to your .xinitrc file to automatically enable shared clipboard on i3 exec.

*Note: although rsynnest's comment does contain the solution it's slightly confusing / inaccurate hence why I made this comment.*

Answer (score 1):

i3 inside a desktop environment of your choice should restore the shared clipboard functionality. 
I have i3+gnome running on Arch guest with Windows 7 host. 
I haven't yet gotten shared clipboard to work for i3 alone, will update this answer if I figure it out.

EDIT: For Arch linux, after installing [virtualbox-guest-utils](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VirtualBox#Install_the_Guest_Additions) I can run `/usr/bin/VBoxClient-all` and it enables all guest services. For some reason the vboxguest systemd service doesn't work as it does in Gnome, but if I put /usr/bin/VBoxClient-all in my PostLogin GDM file it works!

Arch Wiki Resource: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VirtualBox#Launch_the_VirtualBox_guest_services

Comment: If you want to post comments get the 15 reputation that it requires by posting one good answer or question

Comment: It's 50 rep to comment but thanks for the helpful tip. If you read my answer it does contain a solution to his problem: using i3 in combination with a DE will restore clipboard functionality. Will edit for clarity.

Comment: **Your original revision didn't contain an actual solution.**  You only changed it after I said something.  I am familiar with a ton of shorthands for technology and software but never in 20 years herd of "DE"

Comment: From my original answer: 
"i3+Gnome shared clipboard works fine, but i3 alone doesn't have it."

From Wikipedia:
"In computing, a desktop environment (DE) is... "